# MySql how to display data from multiple tables only once?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database - "region" and "attraction". I made a JOIN query that will get data from both of them and I am displaying it afther that. Here is my code:

```
$regionsId = $_GET['region']; 

//$sql    = "SELECT `RegionID`, `RegionName`  FROM `region` WHERE `RegionID`='$regionsId'";
//$sql    = "SELECT `AttractionID`, `Name`, `imglink2`  FROM `attractions` WHERE `RegionID`='$regionsId'";

$sql ="SELECT * 
FROM region
INNER JOIN attractions WHERE region.RegionID = '$regionsId' AND attractions.RegionID = '$regionsId'";


$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}



while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo $row['RegionName']; 

    echo "<a href='attraction.php?village=" . $row['AttractionID'] . "'>" .  "<br />" .
          $row['Name']  .
           "<br />" .

         "<img src='" . $row['imglink2'] . "' height='130' width='150'> 

       </a>";



}





mysql_free_result($result);



 ?>
```

My problem is that When I display it the echo $row['RegionName'];  is displayed multiple times, with every attraction I am displaying. How can I make it so that it is displayed only once?
Thank you.

Comment: Go and look again at basic join syntax

Comment: Well you were of SO much help, thanks....

Answer (score 0):

TRy [GROUP  BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
 $sql ="
SELECT *
FROM region 
LEFT JOIN attractions ON region.RegionID = attractions.RegionID 
WHERE region.RegionID = '$regionsId'
  AND attractions.RegionID = '$regionsId'
GROUP BY region.RegionID" ;
```

Comment: This only displays one attraction.

Comment: Ok.. `SELECT *
FROM region 
LEFT JOIN attractions ON region.RegionID = attractions.RegionID 
WHERE region.RegionID = '$regionsId'
  AND attractions.RegionID = '$regionsId'
` Try this

Comment: No, this doesn't work too. If I take out RegionName out of the while loop it doesn't display it at all. I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM region 
  LEFT JOIN attractions ON region.RegionID = attractions.RegionID 
WHERE region.RegionID = '$regionsId'
  AND attractions.RegionID = '$regionsId'
GROUP BY region.RegionID";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.  SQL will return values in a table format with all "cells" completely filled in:

```
region     attraction
   A          1
   A          2
   A          3
   B          1
   B          5
```

If you want it in this form:

```
   A           1,2,3
   B           1,5
```

Then the database is appropriate:

```
SELECT r.*, group_concat(a.AttractionId)
FROM region r LEFT JOIN
     attractions a
     ON r.RegionID = a.RegionID 
WHERE r.RegionID = '$regionsId'
GROUP BY r.RegionID;
```

If you want it in this form:

```
region     attraction
   A          1
              2
              3
   B          1
              5
```

Then you should do the work in the application layer.  It is possible to set this up in the database, but it "violates" the nature of SQL in dealing with tables.  And, it is pretty easy to do by looping through the results as you display them.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way to go would be to add `order by RegionName` to your query and then, change your code to watch for region change and display it only when change happens, like this:

```
$prevRegionName = ''; // fill variable with something that won't be matched in first comparison

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $currentRegionName = $row['RegionName']; // push current region to variable
    if ($currentRegionName != $prevRegionName) echo $row['RegionName'];  // print region only if it changed

    echo "<a href='attraction.php?village=" . $row['AttractionID'] . "'>" .  "<br />" .
          $row['Name']  .
           "<br />" .

          "<img src='" . $row['imglink2'] . "' height='130' width='150'> 

         </a>";


    $prevRegionName = $currentRegionName; // save current region to compare it in next interaction
    }
```

Comment: if you think my answer is the one you were looking for, please mark it as one.